# Button Action Issue in IOS

Tags: ios6

This is the code i have used.

In View Controller A:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 70, 40)];
    [button setTitle:@"Next View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(nextView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}

-(void) nextView
{
    SecondviewController *secondView = [[SecondviewController alloc] init];

    [self.view addSubview:secondView.view];
}
```

In View Controller B:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 70, 40)];
    [button setTitle:@"Previous View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(previousView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}

-(void) previousView
{

    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

**Issue**: When i click the button in the view controller B, its not switching back to the view controller A...

Comment: When posting code blocks you need to indent 4 spaces to format correctly (fixed).

Answer (score 0):

You are not switching viewControllers, you are taking the view from viewController B and adding it as a subview to viewController A.

Here:

```
     SecondviewController *secondView = [[SecondviewController alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:secondView.view];
```

You need to navigate to the new view *Controller*... Replace it with this for example

```
    SecondviewController *secondViewController = [[SecondviewController alloc] init];       
    [self presentViewController:secondViewController animated:YES completion:NIL];
```

(it's best to include 'controller' when naming controllers to avoid confusion with their views)

Then to return, you need to dismiss the presented viewcontroller...

In ViewControllerB replace this:

```
   [self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

With

```
[[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NIL];
```

This is sending a message back from the presented viewController - viewController B - to the presenting viewController, viewControllerA which does the actual dismissing.

Answer (score 0):

instead of adding a the second subview to the first subview, you need to present or push the view controller in the stack. You are just simply adding it as a subview.

```
 SecondviewController *secondView = [[SecondviewController alloc] init];
 [self presentViewController:secondView animated:NO completion:nil];
```

In the second view controller when you dismiss it you can just simply dismiss/pop it from the stack.

```
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Hi AmitApollo..I got fixed the issue by using ur code. Thank u very much. I have one more query in UItextview. I need to show large amount of text as description in my app..I have used UItextview for this case.But I couldnt scroll to see the full text.. My code is:                    desc = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 360, 300, 300)];
    desc.text = @"More no of lines text goes here.....";

Comment: Look into UIScrollView. There should be plenty of documentation to get you started with this control.